# Property does not exist on type Theme from Emotion

Tags: typescript, emotion

I faced with a problem. When i try to read some parameters from theme-object, or destruсt it - i got an error

> Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Theme'.

I created types.d.ts file, and added it there, but it doesn't help.

```
import '@emotion/react';
import { themeConfig } from './lib/theme';

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends themeConfig {}
}
```

Code of my "custom-provider"

```
// Import modules
import React from 'react';
import {
  css,
  Global, 
  Theme,
  ThemeProvider
} from '@emotion/react';

// Init Theme Config
export const themeConfig = {
  typography: {...},
  palette: {...}
};

interface Props {
  theme: Theme;
}

// Create custom ThemeProvider
export const Provider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, theme = themeConfig }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={ theme }>
    <Global
      styles={(theme) => {
        console.log(theme.palette); <- Here an error
        return css``;
      }}
    />
    { children }
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

### **UPD:**

Solved the problem with change types.d.ts like this

```
type ThemeConfig = typeof themeConfig;
declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends ThemeConfig {}
}
```

Comment: If you solve an issue yourself, you can write is as an answer to your question.